# Call command-line oriented script from another python script

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am using a script written in Python that uses the argparse module to get it's arguments from command line. I try to modify this file as less as possible as various people work on it.

Ex: script is called CLscript.py and I call it with

```
python CLscript.py -option1 arg1 -flag1 -option2 arg2
```

But I'm facing the case where I would like to automate things one level higher and automatically launch this script with wide range of script-generated arguments.

I would like to keep using all the existing organisation of options and flags available in this script.

For example, when I run CLscript.py from topLevelScript.py through :

```
subprocess.call("python CLscript.py -option1 arg1 -flag1 -option2 arg2")
```

,and I see from the output that something is going wrong, I stop the execution topLevelScript.py, but CLscript.py continue to run independently in another python process that I Have to kill manually. I cannot neither launch topLevelScript.py in debug mode to stop at a breakpoint in CLscript.py.

I would like to do this all from inside python, without building a command line string and launching CLscript.py with a subprocess.
Every call would remains attached to the same original launch, just like a function call, and not creating multiple python threads like it would do with a subprocess.call() .

Something like passing a list of string with options, flags and arguments somehow to the script maybe?

Is there something like

```
import CLscript.py
CLsimulator(CLscript,["-option1",arg1,"-flag1","-option2",arg2])
```

Comment: "creating multiple python threads like it would do with a subprocess.call()" - `subprocess` module is not related to threads.

Comment: Actually I am not quite clear what you want to do, would you please specify it more detailed or give an example?

Comment: "Something like passing a list of string with options, flags and arguments" - first argument for `subprocess.call()` is a list of strings.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo see my edits for why I try not to use subprocess.call()

Comment: @antoine seems like `call()` is the only function in `subprocess` module you've read about. Preparing answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen and not `subprocess.call()`:

```
import subprocess

child = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', 'CLscript.py', '-option1', 'arg1', '-flag1', '-option2', 'arg2'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Please notice that as the first argument you pass an `array of strings` just like you want.
Secondly redirection of standard file descriptors will be important. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE.
Now you have `child` variable which holds instance of `Popen` class.
What you can do with this instance?

```
# Check if child is terminated and possibly get the returncode
child.poll()
# Write to child's standard input by a file-like object accessible with
child.stdin
# Read child's standard output and standard error by file-like objects accesible with
child.stdout
child.stderr
```

You said you wanted to detect if something goes wrong in the child process from it's output.
Don't you find `stdout` and `stderr` quite useful for this case?
Now you wanted to terminate the child if you detected that something went wrong.

```
child.kill()
child.terminate()
child.send_signal(signal)
```

If in the end you are sure that everything went well but you want to let child finalize normally, you should use

```
child.wait()
```

or even better

```
child.communicate()
```

because `communicate` will handle lots of output properly.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I thougt before of Popen as some low-level thing I shouldn't touch and use call instead, but like this it doesn't seems so complicated. Thank you!

Comment: @antoine `subprocess.call(...)` is actually a shorthand for `child = subprocess.Popen(...)` without pipes to stdin, stdout, stderr followed by `child.wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?  Extract most of your code into a new function that expects arguments similar to the ones you send in via the command line.  Then write a new function that gathers the command line arguments and sends them to the first function ...

```
def main(foo, bar):
    a = foo + bar
    print a

def from_command_line():
    foo, bar = get_command_line_args()
    main(foo, bar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from_command_line()
```

Then your other scripts can just call the main function.

Comment: That would be a neat way to handle the problem, I like the idea, thank you. Nevertheless in my particular case, as it's a cooperative project, I cannot modify this file and Elmo's answer allows me to do it.