# Running parametric .py file from another code

Tags: python, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a python script that is coded to get arguments from command line. The arguments are processed with the parser inside the py file.
e.g.

> code-file.py -argument1 value1 -argument2 value2

Now what I need to do is taking control of the file with its arguments inside another code. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call command-line oriented script from another python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608303/call-command-line-oriented-script-from-another-python-script)

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot.